# Centering a sticky navigation bar and extending the border using affix bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recreated the issue I am having here:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10279/

```css
/*main-navigation*/
/*view the list as a whole*/
.nav ul{
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #292929;
 text-align: center;
}

/*properties of each list item independently*/
.nav li {
 font-family: proximanova-regular-webfont;
 font-size: 30px;

 /*display in horizontal order*/
 display: inline-block; 
}


.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 
 padding-right: 60px;
 padding-left: 60px;
 
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}



.nav a:hover, .nav a:focus,.nav a:active , #mainnav a.thispage{
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #292929;
 -o-transition:.675s;
 -ms-transition:.675s;
 -moz-transition:.675s;
 -webkit-transition:.675s;
 transition:.675s;
}

#main p {
 font-family: "proximanova light";
 color: #000000;
 font-size: xx-large;
 text-align: center;
 width: 44%;
 margin-left: 50%;
 margin-right: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="link_affix">
    <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
        <div class="nav">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage">HOME</a></li>
               <li><a href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
               <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.html\n">CONTACT </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> 
 </div> <!-- affix -->
</div>


<article id="main">
  <p>
example textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample 
</p>

</article>
```

My goal is to achieve two things:

1. Center the text and navigation bar.
2. Extend the border towards both ends of the window. (just as stackexchange does).

I've done my research and tried many things, but to no avail. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: why all styling to create a  navigation bar their are bootstrap class use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following style you should be able to center the nave and make it spread across the whole screen:

```
.affix {left:0; right:0;}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10285/)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically it is adding a class `.affix`.

You have `position:fixed` to `.affix` override that to `position:relative`

```
 .affix {
  position:relative;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10284/